# How to deal with "could not convert string to float" error

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This question has been asked several times here and I checked most of them, but couldn't figure out how to deal with it.
I read a CSV file and I try to convert its values to float as following:

```
testdataframe = pd.read_csv(r'H:\myCSVfile.csv')
testdataset = testdataframe.values
testdataset = testdataset.astype('float32')
```

I get this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020-08-05 22:45:00'

here is testdataframe:

```
array([['2020-08-05 22:45:00', 5.670524],   
   ['2020-08-05 23:00:00', 5.6840434],  
   ['2020-08-05 23:15:00', 5.6911097],  
   ['2020-08-05 23:30:00', 5.6869917],  
   ['2020-08-05 23:45:00', 5.6786237],  
   ['2020-08-06 00:00:00', 5.6710806]], dtype=object
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That is clearly a date/time string.  Why are you trying to convert it to a float?

Comment: @JohnGordon  You are right!!!! I didn't need it. I only need the second column values. So I modified the first line as follows and it solved my problem. Many thanks for pointing it out :)                   testdataframe = pd.read_csv(r'H:\myCSVfile.csv',usecols=[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) correctly mentioned that it is a date/time string
You should apply `astype(float)` to numeric columns. However, if you still want to proceed with applying the same, here goes the logic to ignore 'errors'

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.2,'1.2','a'],"B":['2020-10-2 10:00:00','2020-10-2 11:00:00','2020-10-2 12:00:00']})
df.astype(float, errors='ignore')
```